# How to make org-babel evaluate noweb reference only once?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

To get user input for a shell script, I prepared an emacs-lisp source block.

```el
#+name: get_text_from_user
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
    (let ((text (read-from-minibuffer "Enter some text> ")))
        text
    )
#+end_src
    
#+begin_src shell :noweb yes
    echo <<get_text_from_user()>>
#+end_src
```

This works, **but the user is prompted for input a total of 3 times**, instead of just once. How can this behavior be fixed?

**-- Update --**

The issue seems to be related to this configuration:

```el
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
   (not (member lang '("shell" "emacs-lisp"))))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```

Comment: I see no reason why the user is prompted 3 times and indeed when I try it out for myself, I cannot reproduce the behavior: I'm prompted *once* every time I `C-c C-c` the code block and whatever I type appears as the result each time. Do you get a result printed out? Do you get a "Code block evaluation complete" message? If you type a different string each time, what result is printed out?

Comment: Can you provide a recipe for reproducing the behavior starting from `emacs -q`? AFAICT, the code you point to is not used above, so I'm not sure how exactly you pinned the problem to it. In particular, show the complete file and describe what you do as exactly as possible to get the behavior you describe.

Comment: That code was not the problem. I deleted my comment with the wrong reference and updated the question.

Comment: Now I can reproduce it - thanks!